# What does it mean if someone is a "minefield of information"

Tags: phrases

What does it mean if someone says that "you're a minefield of information" - after you gave them some useful information. 
Perhaps they meant "mine of information"?
What do both those phrases mean?

Comment: If someone says *"you're a minefield of information"* they're either not a competent native speaker, or they're making a somewhat obscure joke implying that asking you about anything may be dangerous (because your information is unreliable, perhaps). Whatever - it's Too Localised.

Comment: Related (somewhat belatedly): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism

Comment: To summarize the comments, this phrase is a mistake or humorous. The natural phrase is a metaphor 'a mine of information', a person that is chock full of interesting facts. Changing that to 'minefield' would mean that each little (very mixed metaphor) of jewels would explode on you, a great mistake in understanding, or a very particular sardonic statement about someone's knowledge base.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Minefield* is often used figuratively to refer to something dangerous – to something that may seem harmless, but really isn't.  NOAD reads:

> **minefield** (figurative): *a subject or situation presenting unseen hazards : a minefield of technical regulations.*

There's also a common idiom: *he knows just enough to be dangerous*, which is used when someone has just a little bit of knowledge about something, but is not very proficient.  That little bit of knowledge can give a person a false sense of confidence that can eventually lead to trouble.   (For example, if you know a little bit about engines, you might start taking one apart, only to find out you're not going to fix the engine – and you might even have trouble putting it back together again.)

*Minefield of information* is not an established idiom; it might have been misspoken, misheard, or else it's someone trying to say something humorous, playing off of *mine of information,* which is used to refer to a person or database where much valuable information can be gleaned.  If that information is sometimes faulty, one might say something like:

> Watch out for Wikipedia! It's a minefield of information.

which I think reads rather clever, but it's **not** an established idiom. That said, it's not completely original, either; [**others have used it**](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22mine%20of%20information%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1975,cd_max:2005&lr=lang_en#q=%22minefield+of+information%22&hl=en&lr=lang_en&sa=X&tbs=lr%3alang_1en%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1975%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2005&tbm=bks&fp=1&biw=1341&bih=876&cad=b).

Comment: +1 for excellent example *Wikipedia is a **minefield** of information*. The rest of the answer is all good too, even though I think the question itself is too localised. As you say, it's not an established idiom - as a witticism it's probably been "coined" repeatedly, but most usages are probably just ignorant "mixed metaphors" anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The idiom I'm used to is "a gold mine of information about X," meaning someone who's willing and able to tell you a whole bunch about X. [Here's](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/gold+mine+of+information) a (not very detailed) verifying link.

Comment: Per [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gold+mine+of+information%2Cgoldmine+of+information%2Cmine+of+information&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), the word "gold" can precede "mine of information", but usually it doesn't.

Comment: +1. Clearly "minefield" is a mis-spoken version of "gold mine".

Answer (score 1):

This is rather late in the day for the question, but I only now stumbled upon this thread...

The expression "minefield of information" may be a reference to an Afrikaans novel, "Griet Skryf 'n Sprokie" by Marita van der Vyver (apparently "[Entertaining Angels](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0140231552)" in English). In it, the protagonist at one point tells her best friend, after he (as is typical for him) told her an obscure fact:

> You're a veritable minefield of useless information - I never know when the
>   next explosion is going to hit me <sup>[translation from the German version mine, quoted from memory]</sup>

This is pretty self-explanatory, I suppose. I always thought it a rather clever image - but of course it only makes sense if the second part isn't left out.